# It's neither a shoulder belt, a baldric, nor a sash. What is it, then?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

Aristotle never dreamed of wearing anything like it, but Rembrandt had to put it there to balance out the composition. What is that glittering thing, with some kind of medallion/pendant hanging from it halfway from Aristotle's left hand to Homer's head?

Comment: Are you sure it's not splitting halfway (rather than being a medallion) and passing around his waist?

Comment: @KillingTime: No, I'm not.

Answer (score 3):

It's a jeweled ***belt***.

> belt: a flexible band, as of leather or cloth, worn around the waist or over a shoulder to support clothing, secure tools or weapons, or serve as decoration. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/belt)
>
> *Aristotle, world-weary, looks at the bust of blind, humble Homer, on which he rests one of his hands. This has variously been interpreted
>   as the man of sound, methodical science deferring to Art, or as the
>   wealthy and famous philosopher, wearing the **jeweled belt** given to
>   him by Alexander the Great, envying the life of the poor blind bard.
>   It has also been suggested that this is Rembrandt's commentary on the
>   power of portraiture.*
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle_with_a_Bust_of_Homer)

Comment: I think it is a *chain* rather than a *belt*. There are many sources calling that accessory a chain (specifically a gold chain). For example: http://www.artchive.com/artchive/R/rembrandt/aristotl.jpg.html