# What is the name for the flat attire worn over the shoulders at academic graduations?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example of the specific article of interest is the flat, light blue item worn by each individual in the below photo:

[image: Graduation photo from illinois.edu]

<sub>*(Photo source: http://graduation.aces.illinois.edu/sites/graduation.aces.illinois.edu/themes/sitetheme/templates/images/Graduation-Large-Box-01.jpg, accessed 21 Feb 2016)*</sub>

It does not appear to fit the definition of a [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sash) or [baldric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldric) or [shoulder belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_belt_(military)) (these three drawn from [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289356/its-neither-a-shoulder-belt-a-baldric-nor-a-sash-what-is-it-then) English.SE question), but I may be interpreting the definitions of these too strictly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Graduation stole*** or [***academic stole***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_stole):

> A stole takes the form of a cloth scarf-like garment worn over the shoulders adorned with the awarding Society's colours and/or insignia. Though not a part of officially recognised American Council on Education's Academic Costume Code, it has become common as part of the graduation attire at many high schools, colleges, and universities.

Here's a photo from the same page with the graduation stole highlighted:

[image]
<sup>By Valedictorian_Joint-Chiefs-of-Staff.jpg: Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staffderivative work: Themightyquill - This file was derived from  Valedictorian Joint-Chiefs-of-Staff.jpg:, CC BY 2.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=20548944</sup>

[Wikipedia]

Apparently, the term ***graduation sash*** is common too:

> The colors of graduation hoods, cap tassels and stoles, ***also called graduation sashes***, are governed by traditions from the Middle Ages, reports the American Council on Education, or ACE. [[ehow.com](http://www.ehow.com/list_7384110_color-meanings-graduation-stoles_.html)]

However, a *sash* typically goes diagonally across the body, like what pageant queens wear (see WBT's comment below). Sticking to *stole* is the safest thing to do.

Comment: Think I knew this at one time, but it'd completely slipped my mind. Thanks!

Comment: A sash typically goes diagonally across the body, like what pageant queens wear.

Comment: @WBT Not according to [this page](https://thesashcompany.com/faq-ordering-info): *While technically a "sash" is a garment that goes across the body from one shoulder to the opposite hip, when it comes to graduation sashes vs. stoles, both terms are used interchangeably. Both refer to the classic graduation garment that goes across the shoulders, with both ends falling vertically down the body. So really, there is no difference — Graduation stoles and Graduation Sashes are the same thing.*

Comment: @Yay that company has a vested interest in getting people to use the word "sash" as interchangeable for "stole" as widely as possible, because of how they named their company and how they want to expand into a new lucrative market.  Also, the quote (esp. first clause) echoes my comment (which did include "typically") more than it opposes it.

Comment: @WBT Okay then. I've already edited my aswer.